# Proving a set is positive invariant for non-linear system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, nonlinear-system, lyapunov-functions, set-invariance

The system is:
\begin{align}
\dot{x_1} &= -x_1 \\
\dot{x_2} &= (x_1x_2-1)x_2^3 +(x_1x_2 - 1 +x_1^2)x_2
\end{align}

I'm trying to prove the following set is positive invariant:
\begin{equation}
\Omega_c = \{ x \in \mathbb{R^2} \mid x_1x_2 \ge 2\}
\end{equation}

A positive invariant set is such that:
\begin{equation}
\Omega_c = \{ x \in \mathbb{R^2} \mid V(x) \le c \} \;\; with \;\; \dot{V} \le 0 \;\; in \;\; \Omega_c  
\end{equation}

I analyzed the derivative of the Lyapunov function $V(x_1, x_2) = x_1x_2$:
\begin{equation}
\dot{V} = x_1x_2(x_1^2 + x_1x_2^3 + x_1x_2 - x_2^2 - 2)
\end{equation}

But it seems like for $x_1x_2 \ge 2$ we have $\dot{V} > 0$.

I would appreciate some help!

Comment: Define $z=x_1x_2$, find $\dot z$ and show that it is non-negative for $z>2$.

Comment: @Arastas, shouldn't I prove its negativeness for $z \ge 2$?

Comment: You want to show that if $z \ge 2$, it will never become below 2.

Comment: @Arastas, but according to the definition of positive invariant set I should prove $\dot{V} \le 0, \forall  x \in \Omega_c$, I don't get your point.

Comment: I suggest you put your definition of positive invariant in the text of your question.

Comment: Alright, I added the definition!

Comment: Your $V$ is not a Lyapunov function, as it is not bounded from below. However, if you want to do it that way, define $V = -x_1x_2$. Then show that $\dot V\le 0$ for $V\le c = -2$.

Answer (score 1):

The goal of a positive invariant set $\Omega_c$ is that once $x(t)\in\Omega_c$ we have that for all $t'\geq t \Rightarrow x(t')\in\Omega_c$.

If $\varphi$ is a real valued function such that $\frac d{dt}(x(t))>0$ and $\Omega_c=\{x:\varphi(x)\geq c\}$ we can show that $\Omega_c$ is such a set. Switching the direction of the inequalities will yield an equivalent definition.

$\dot{x}_1 x_2 = -x_1x_2$ and $x_1\dot{x}_2=x_1x_2[(x_1x_2-1)(x_2^2+1)+x_1^2]$. Thus:

$$\dot V = x_1x_2[(x_1x_2-1)(x_2^2+1)+x_1^2-1]\geq 2[x_2^2+x_1^2]\geq 4x_1x_2\geq 8>0$$